"n_unique" aggregation using DuckDB relational API
Say I have
import duckdb

rel = duckdb.sql('select * from values (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6) df(a, b)')
rel

Out[3]: 
┌───────┬───────┐
│   a   │   b   │
│ int32 │ int32 │
├───────┼───────┤
│     1 │     4 │
│     1 │     5 │
│     2 │     6 │
└───────┴───────┘

I can group by a and find the mean of 'b' by doing:
rel.aggregate(
    [duckdb.FunctionExpression('mean', duckdb.ColumnExpression('b'))],
    group_expr='a',
)

┌─────────┐
│ mean(b) │
│ double  │
├─────────┤
│     4.5 │
│     6.0 │
└─────────┘

which works wonderfully
Is there a similar way to create a "n_unique" aggregation? I'm looking for something like
rel.aggregate(
    [duckdb.FunctionExpression('count_distinct', duckdb.ColumnExpression('b'))],
    group_expr='a',
)

but that doesn't exist. Is there something that does?

updated.
I couldn't find proper way of doing count distinct, but you could use combination of array_agg() and array_unique() functions:
rel.aggregate(
    [duckdb.FunctionExpression(
        'array_unique',
        duckdb.FunctionExpression(
            'array_agg',
            duckdb.ColumnExpression('b')
        )
    )],
    group_expr='a',
)

┌────────────────────────────┐
│ array_unique(array_agg(b)) │
│           uint64           │
├────────────────────────────┤
│                          1 │
│                          2 │
└────────────────────────────┘

old.
you can pre-select distinct a and b columns?
(
    rel.select(*[duckdb.ColumnExpression('a'), duckdb.ColumnExpression('b')])
    .distinct()
    .aggregate(
        [duckdb.FunctionExpression('count', duckdb.ColumnExpression('b'))],
        group_expr='a',
    )
)


no, i need to create an expression
